# Node get string/value from a php file

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, gulp

I have the following code in a php file:

```
<?php
    //some code before...
    define('VERSION', 8);

    //some more code after...
?>
```

Is it possible to use node to grab the value `8` from the constant?

I'm using

```
fs.readFile("includes/my_file.php", "utf8", function(error, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

to read the file but not sure if I can actually grab the constant.

note: this is for a gulp script

Comment: What gets logged from `data`?

Comment: Just the contents of the php file with utf8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

Put your version to JSON file. If you use node modules then it could be the **package.json** -file.

Then in your PHP:

```
$packageStr = file_get_contents('package.json');
$settings = json_decode($packageStr, true);
define('VERSION', $settings['version']);
```

And in gulp:

```
var package = require('./package.json');
var version = package.version;
```